# Regex to change case of properties in eclipse

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I have a lot of POJO's in a java project with incorrect names and need to change the same in eclipse, I need a regex that will select the first letters in a class file.

```
For Eg:
    private Long GenericMasterId;
    private String MasterType;
    private int MasterId;
```

In the above code i must be able to select letters "G", "M" and "M" which is the first letter of the property names.

I have made a regex [\s\S]{0,2}$ but it does not work as expected, any help is highly appretiated.

Comment: `[\s\S]{0,2}$` does not work as expected because 1) you did not actually explain the requirements, 2) you expect Eclipse regex to be able to turn captures into lower- or   uppercase, but it just can't.

Comment: I have updated the question, hope it explains the requirement now. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=\s)\w(?=\w*\s*;\s*$)
```

- `(?<=\s)` - whitespace (but without matching it)
- `\w` - alphanumeric character
- `(?=\w*\s*;\s*$)` - followed by alphanumeric characters, `;` and line end (but without matching it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
^.*\s([A-Z]).*;$
```

To break this down a bit:

- '^' = start of line
- '.*' = and amount of characters
- '\s' = some whitespace

now, this is the bit we are interested in:

- '([A-Z])' = select this letter!
- '.*' = any amount of letters ...
- ';$' = ... that end the line with a ';' character

Which is basically saying "select the first uppercase letter of a word which ends the line with a ';' character.

Comment: this is working but it is selecting the entire line, i only want it to select the first character of the third word. thanks in advance.